# Is using a WebServer as a proxy a secure solution

Tags: webserver, proxy, http-proxy

There are 2 machines - both running Windows Server.

Machine1 can access the internet. Machine2 cannot access the internet, but can access Machine1.

Machine2 needs to continuously access one external `https` GET URL on the internet. So the way I was thinking of doing this is by running a lightweight proxy server on Machine1 using this as a proxy for Machine2 to access the external URL.
(I know that a better/more secure solution may be to have let Machine2 access the internet with a firewall blocking everything except the required connection - but unfortunately that is not possible in this case because various reasons)

After searching around, it seems that the general approach is to use a Webserver (Apache/nginx/IIS) running on Machine1 as a forward proxy server - there seem to be very few independent proxy servers available any more - the few independent proxies available don't seem to in active developement or support.

Is this approach secure - i.e. can Webservers be locked down securely enough so that they only serve as proxies and not add anly additional security issues? What kind of problems should I be wary of?

Comment: Yah this one is perfect solutions But i think if you have good knowledge of linux then use linux proxy and also configure firewall configurations on linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you're running a relatively modern version of windows server (2008 or 2012) I think you can do this with inbuilt server functionality.

The [netsh interface portproxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command allows you to setup proxying/port forwarding on a windows server.  If possible I'd say go with a solution that uses OS functionality as it reduces the complexity and doesn't give you another piece of software to maintain/patch .

As to the approach of using a webserver as the proxy, that could work ok.  If you go that way it would be a case of locking down the server as much as possible and then making sure it was added to the patching process to make sure it gets updated.

Comment: I checked out the netsh interface proxy command. Looks like it will not be a general purpose proxy because it will forward only to one outgoing IP address - is this correct? Not that it matters to my use case - but just want to understand this better

Comment: no I don't believe it would work as a general proxy, but should work ok in your case.

Comment: great! Thank you. Last question - it should be able to handle multiple requests and concurrent requests etc, right?

Comment: BTW - for future users - this also works on Win2003 Server as long as you install and enable IPV6 on it (ipv6 is needed even if both the input & output ports are ipv4).